JToken.FromObject adds square brackets for child
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    Dim dtTICKET As New DataTable
    dtTICKET.Columns.Add("Title", GetType(String))
    dtTICKET.Columns.Add("Queue", GetType(String))
    
    dtTICKET.Rows.Add("New Updates", "Updates")
    'dtTICKET.Rows.Add("Lost connection", "Network")
    
    Dim dtJSON As New DataTable
    dtJSON.Columns.Add("UserLogin", GetType(String))
    dtJSON.Columns.Add("Password", GetType(String))
    dtJSON.Columns.Add("Ticket", GetType(DataTable))
    
    dtJSON.Rows.Add("user@domain.de", "pwd", dtTICKET)
    
    json = JToken.FromObject(dtJSON).ToString()     
End Sub

executing this code results in
    [
      {
        "UserLogin": "user@domain.de",
        "Password": "pwd",
        "Ticket": [
          {
            "Title": "New Updates",
            "Queue": "Updates"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

but I need curly brackets instead of square brackets for the child "Ticket" if dtTicket only has one row
I tried to use a custom JsonSerializer and set IndentChar for Formatting. But I don't know if that is the right way and how to do this
Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Dim dtTICKET As New DataTable ie dtTICKET is a datatable and the serialization of a datatable is an array. If you only have a single ticket, consider creating a plain object instead of a datatable ...

you are right. My REST API needs a single ticket. For that I dont need an array, I created a plain object for dtJson and dtTicketas suggested from @BitRebus

I created a plain object for dtJson and dtTicket because my REST API needs a single ticket and by that it works
Public Class Ticket
    Public Title As String
    Public QueueID As String
    Public TypeID As String
    Public State As String
    Public Priority As String
    Public CustomerUser As String
    Public Article As DataTable
End Class

Public Class Json
    Public UserLogin As String
    Public Password As String
    Public Ticket As Ticket        
End Class

